# How to synchronize concurrent writes and close

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a custom writer as follow:

```
public class MyWriter{
public void write(StuffToWrite stuff){
/*
do the write here
*/
}

public void close(){
/*
do the close here
*/
}
}
```

which would be accessed by multiple concurrent threads, no problem if write method called concurrentlty.
I want to make sure that close method never executed if any thread is in middle/or just starting the writing and waits for every already-started writes to finish. How to accompolish this?

P.S. One suggestion is to use an AtomicInteger flag which would be increased/decreased by 2 on write and increased by 1 in close method, something like this:

```
   public class MyWriter
{

  AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInterger (0);

  public void write (StuffToWrite stuff)
  {
    counterValue = counter.getAndAdd (2);
    if (counterValue % 2 != 0)
      {
    throw new RuntimeException ("Already closed");
      }
    else
      {
    /*
       do the write here
     */
    counterValue = counter.getAndAdd (-2);
    if (counterValue == 1)
      {
        doClose ();
      }
      }
  }

  public void close ()
  {
    int counterValue = counter.get ();
    if (counterValue % 2 != 0)
      return;           //some thread already closed it
    else if (counterValue > 0)
      {             //eben and > 0, so in middle of write
    counter.getAndAdd (1);
      }
    else
      {             // == 1, so no pending writes and should be closed
    counter.getAndAdd (1);
    doClose ();
      }
  }

  private void doClose ()
  {
    /*
       do the close here
     */
  }

}
```

PS2:
Currently this solution (combination of a blocking/non-blocking algurithms) works for me:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MyWriter {

    Queue<String> globalQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

    AtomicBoolean isClosed1 = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    AtomicBoolean isClosed2 = new AtomicBoolean(false);


    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);


    public void write(List<String> toBeWrote) {
        for (; ; ) {// a non atomic check-then-modify.
            int old_state = counter.get();
            if (isOdd(old_state)) {
                throw new ClosedGracefullyException("gracefully closed");
            }
            int new_state = old_state + 2;
            if (counter.compareAndSet(old_state, new_state)) break;
        }
        doTheWrite(toBeWrote);
        int counterValue = counter.getAndAdd(-2);
        if (counterValue == 1) {
            doClose();
        }
    }

    private boolean isOdd(int old_state) {
        return old_state % 2 != 0;
    }

    private boolean isEven(int old_state) {
        return old_state % 2 == 0;
    }

    private void doTheWrite(List<String> toBeWrote) {
        for (String s : toBeWrote) {
            globalQueue.add(s);
            if (isFullyClosed()) {
                throw new ClosedUnexpectedlyException("this writer closed!!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void synchronized close() {
        int old_state = counter.get();
        if (isOdd(old_state)) {
            return;
        } else if (counter.compareAndSet(0, 1)) {
            doClose();
        } else { //even and > 0, so in middle of write
            counter.getAndAdd(1);
        }
    }

    private void doClose() {
        isClosed1.getAndSet(true);
        isClosed2.getAndSet(true);
    }

    private boolean isFullyClosed() {
        return isClosed1.get() && isClosed2.get();
    }

    public List<String> getContents() {
        return Arrays.asList(globalQueue.toArray(new String[0]));
    }
}
```

I use this unit test to validate the solution:

```
 @Test
    public void testConcurrency() throws Exception {

        int numberOfWriters = 10;
        int numberOfClosers = 3;
        final int maxSleepMillis = 10;
        int numberOfRuns = 500;

        long sumDuration = 0L;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfRuns; k++) {
            myWriter = new MyWriter();
            Thread writers[] = new Thread[numberOfWriters];
            Thread closers[] = new Thread[numberOfClosers];

            final boolean[] exceptionHappened = {false};
            final int[] closedExceptionCount = {0};

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWriters; i++) {
                final int finalI = i;
                writers[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        sleep(maxSleepMillis);
                        try {
                            myWriter.write(Arrays.asList("test"+ finalI));
                        } catch (ClosedUnexpectedlyException e){
                            exceptionHappened[0] = true;
                        } catch (ClosedGracefullyException cwe){
                            //OK
                            closedExceptionCount[0]++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClosers; i++) {
                final int finalI = i;
                closers[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        sleep(maxSleepMillis);
                        myWriter.close();
                    }
                });
            }

            for (Thread writer : writers) {
                writer.start();
            }

            for (Thread closer : closers) {
                closer.start();
            }

            for (Thread writer : writers) {
                writer.join();
            }

            for (Thread closer : closers) {
                closer.join();
            }
            long avgDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / (k+1);
            System.out.println(String.format("run %d, closed Ex: %d , avgDuration: %d" , k, closedExceptionCount[0], avgDuration));
            assertFalse(exceptionHappened[0]);
        }


    }

    private void sleep(int maxSleepMillis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * maxSleepMillis));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The key part is that you need to stick it into a for loop and you get something like:

for(true){long state_state = state.get(); long new_state = ... ; if(state.compareAndSet(old_state,new_new_state)) break;}

Comment: The situation you want to prevent is a non atomic check-then-modify. Otherwise you will end up in a race-condition.

Comment: You also have a problem in your write. Imagine what happens when close is called; then you are going to increment the counter by 2 even though you didn't enter. So I would also do this using a for loop as I described in my first comment.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand, how exactly use the for loop in my code and also how to check % 2 condition with compare and set.

Comment: for(;;}{long old_state = state.get(); if (old_state is odd) throw Exception(); long new_state = old_state +2; if(state.compare_and_set(old_state;new_state)) break;}

Comment: Then the for loop would have negative impact on performance?

Comment: In most cases it will succeed without needing to loop. This is just a security in case the cas did fail and you need to retry.

Comment: @pveentjer I've implemented your suggestion (i hope so), only at write method the for loop needed and in close method it does not seem to be needed?!, anyway still the concurrency unit test fails? I've edited the original post and add the current implementation and the unit test in P.S2, Thanks again for your help

Comment: The close isn't atomic. So you are doing a get and on one of the paths you do an unconditional get and add. If you would have 2 threads calling close concurrently, then it could happen that together they increment by 1+1=2. Then the close won't work because you have introduced a 'writer' instead of introducing a close flag.

Comment: You don't need to use non blocking algorithm btw. You could use use a sync block where you just apply a short sync on write enter and write exit. Perhaps that is a bit simpler and you still keep your desired semantics of concurrent writes. Also the close should use this lock.

Comment: In write method first i check if its odd, i throw exception (which would be handled at upper level)

Comment: My comment about the write wasn't valid, i was looking at some earlier code.

Comment: Are you suggesting that i should keep this solution and only use syncronized blocks when i'm working with the counter-flag?

Comment: Yes. And then you can just call get/set. You can even ditch the atomic long complete and use a regular long for the count and a separate flag for stopping. So you don't need to encode both states into a single field. But you need to make sure that all accesses to these fields is done under the lock, otherwise you will get a data race.

Comment: Synchronized is simpler to program if you don't have much experience with non blocking algorithms.

Comment: I set the whole close method to synchronized and no change to write method, and now the test succeeds

Comment: Also its not that much slow compared to previous solution

Comment: Thanks for your help, what (books, codes, etc) do you recommend for me to get more experienced with non-blocking algs?

Comment: I've edited the P.S2 to be the final working solution

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any books about non blocking algorithms. Probably the best to have a look at projects like JCTools an Aeron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to make all the methods synchronized. This will prevent any concurrent close with write. This will also prevent concurrent writes btw.

If you truly want to have concurrent writes, then just set a flag and let the writers check this flag once they exit the method. This way the last thread that leaves the building can switch off the lights.

General idea: You could encode this information in an AtomicLong. E.g. every time someone enters the write, the counter is incremented by 2 and every time a thread leaves the write method, it decreases the counter by 2.

If a thread wants to enter the write, and sees the counter is odd, then it can return or thrown an exception. Whatever you fancy.

If a thread exits the write, it can reduce the counter by 2 and if 1 remains, this means that this thread is the last one leaving the write method and can complete the close.

If a thread want to close, and the counter is even and larger than 0, increment the counter by 1. If the counter already is odd, then someone else already called the close method and no further actions are needed (make sure you don't increment by 1 again!). If the counter was zero, then there are no writers and you can complete the close from the calling thread (make sure you cas the value to 1 to prevent race conditions).

You can do these state transfers atomically to prevent any race condition using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#compareAndSet-long-long-

Comment: Should it be AtomicLong, or AtomicInteger is OK too?

Comment: Also i don't understand how two separately synchronized methods would also coordinate each other? (although the part that won't let me to have concurrent writes is not good)

Comment: It is fine unless you have more than 2^30 threads :)

Comment: If your writing logic is truly concurrent, then you don't need to have any other synchronization to deal with the closing logic. So an AtomicInteger/Long would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the smart general idea, i will unit-test it, but i was curious about synchronized methods too

Comment: one more thing, these conditions would be if-else that should be checked atomitically, so how to be sure that Atmic number does not change between if and else (which is chekcing with non-atomic value)?

Comment: could you please provide me the implementation of your suggested idea on MyWriter class?

Comment: I would suggest to get started with it and update your question. I'll have a look if you run into problems.

Comment: I updated my question and add the suggestion to the end, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyWriter{
    private final static Lock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();
    public void write(StuffToWrite stuff){
        LOCK.lock();
        /*
        do the write here
        */
    }

    public void close(){
        /*
        do the close here
        */
        LOCK.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't allow concurrent writes nor multiple writes without close..